# jqgrid - remove highlight and input type checked from disabled row

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Below code makes each row checked by default on page load and disable row(s) which has `flag set = 1`.

```
   //disable row which are flagged
    rowattr: function (item) {
            if (parseInt(item.IS_FLAGGED) == 1) {
                return {"class": "ui-state-disabled ui-jqgrid-disablePointerEvents"};
            }
    },

    //prevent selection of disabled rows
    beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {
        if ($(e.target).closest("tr.jqgrow").hasClass("ui-state-disabled")) {
            return false;   // not allow select the row
        }
        return true;    // allow select the row
    },

    loadComplete: function () {
        $("#cb_" + this.id).click(); //enable checkbox on top of multiselect column

            $('input.cbox').prop('checked',true); //enable other checkboxes
            $("tr.jqgrow").addClass('ui-state-highlight'); //highlight row

            //remove highlight and input type checked from disabled row
            if ($("tr.jqgrow").hasClass("ui-state-disabled")) {
            $("tr.jqgrow input.cbox").prop('checked',false);
            $("tr.jqgrow").removeClass("ui-state-highlight"); //enable other checkboxes
        }

    }
```

But on `loadComplete` it also highlight disabled rows. How to remove class `highlight` and set `checked=false` only for those row(s) which has `flag_set = 1` i.e. `disabled`

```
jQgrid version = 4.6
jQuery version = 1.7.2
```

Comment: I posted you already the demo http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/aagxejj5/4/ in the answer on your previous question. The problem which you describes should not exist at all and the callback `loadComplete: function () { $("#cb_" + this.id).click(); }` should do all the work. **So you should have the problem in other part of your code or in combination of the code with data**. I suggested you to modify the http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/aagxejj5/4/ by including your test data which reproduce the problem. Only having the demo which have the problem one can solve it.

Comment: @Oleg, pls see http://jsfiddle.net/aagxejj5/34/. Have similar code but still cant make it work

Comment: Sorry, but which problem exist in the demo http://jsfiddle.net/aagxejj5/34/? The disabled row will be not selected. The code ` $("#cb_" + this.id).click()` do what is expecetd. Which web browser you use in your tests? What problem exist in the demo?

Comment: @Oleg, its could be a possible case of jQuery version. I have `1.7.2` while your fiddle works with 1.10.1. Also if you try and change your fiddle jQuery version to 1.7.2, it won't work. If I update my version to `1.11` it says `$grid.jqGrid` is not a function

Comment: Sorry, I have now no time. I will take a look in the problem later, but I still not understand why you need to use retro version of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I analysed the problem with the usage of old jQuery 1.7.2 and old jqGrid 4.6. The reason is that jQuery 1.7.2 triggers the `click` *before* the checkbox will be changed. So jqGrid don't recognize the click as checking the checkbox and nothing happens. It seems be a bug in jQuery 1.6-1.8, not a bug in jqGrid. jQuery 1.9 and later seems not have such problem.

The main problem is the consequences from the fact. OK, you know now that it's a bug in jQuery 1.7.2. How you can solve the problem? You can rewrite some parts of your code and to implement the workaround in your code so that it will work correctly with the old versions of jQuery and jqGrid. Is it your way?

My recommendation would be update to jQuery 1.11.3 and to consider to update jqGrid to free jqGrid 4.9 (which will be soon published).